# Displaying Image in round shape using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, image, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to show image  in round shape using RoR. Please see my below image tag and help me how can i  convert it into round shape.

```
<%= image_tag(current_user.picture_url, :width => 70,:height => 60 ) %>
```

Don't confused about the line "current_user.picture_url" it is fetching image url from database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not any rocket-science with Rails. It's part of `css`. You can define `class` in `image_tag` and write your css with however style you wanted to give. Like this:

```
<%= image_tag current_user.picture_url ,:class=> "img-circular" %>
```

and in your **application.css** or in your view file write this:

```
<style>  # if you are putting this code in application.css then no need to write <style> tag
.img-circular{
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-size: cover;
 display: block;
 border-radius: 100px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
 -moz-border-radius: 100px;
}
</style>
```

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GaganGami/chebqgrL/1/)

**Note:** Better to use in `application.css` as you can use this class anywhere in your application to apply same style.